# Gradle - Add property files as runtime dependencies

Tags: java, gradle

My property files are currently in src/main/resources but as a read they are by default added to the deployment artifact. How can I add those as runtime dependancies to my project. So far I tried creating a folder - '/resources' and then added the following line to my build.gradle file having the war plugin applied:

```
runtime fileTree(dir: 'resources', include: '*.yaml')
```

Can you guys see anything wrong with that because files are not found at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

Runtime dependencies will be added to the War's `WEB-INF/lib` directory, and you can't put plain files there (only Jars etc.). What's wrong with putting the resource files into `src/main/resources`? What *exact* problem are you trying to solve? Are these static web resources, rather than Java resources? In that case, you can put them into `src/main/webapp`.

Comment: Basically I have domain specific configuration yaml files whose values I'd like to be able to change at runtime. I want to probably have a directory with these files and add them as runtime dependencies and then loading values throughout the course of my program execution.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to keep the YAML files outside the War so that you can edit them while the web application is running?

Comment: But even if those are in the war file I am still gonna be able to amend values after war's been exploded... aren't I :) I am thinking of using one of the Apache Commons' FileConfiguration implementations. There is a load() method which "Load the configuration from the specified file." http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration/FileConfiguration.html

Comment: Then why don't you just put them into `src/main/webapp`?